# Why is my passport js authentication always failing?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I am new to passport.js and I am having trouble authenticating using passport, passport-local- and passport-local-mongoose. It fails every time and I have no idea why this is happening.

I have read many topics on here and elsewhere trying to find a solution. I am also following a video tutorial and have everything setup the same way. For some reason I believe it has to do with my refactoring but I have spent 2 days looking at this and no luck.

Here is my app.js file:

```
var express = require("express");
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
var User = require("./models/user.js");
var Vehicle = require("./models/vehicle.js");
var VehicleData = require("./models/vehicleData.js");
var Admin = require("./models/admin.js");
var passport = require("passport");
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
var loginRoutes = require("./routes/login");
var registerRoutes = require("./routes/register");
//var adminRoutes = require("./routes/admin");

var app = express();

// PAYPAL CONFIGURATION
paypal.configure({//LEFT THIS OUT OF CODE ON PURPOSE});

//setting up the routes
app.use("/login", loginRoutes);
app.use("/register", registerRoutes);
//app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);

//EJS
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//BODY PARSER
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//setting the root of the website
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

//express-session settings
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "I hope this all goes well",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

//passport settings
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// MONGOOSE
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("main/index");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
    console.log("Connected to server on " + process.env.IP + ":" + process.env.PORT);
});
```

Here is the user.js file:

```
var mongoose              = require("mongoose"),
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        first: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        last: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        }
    },
    username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            //trim: true,
            //lowercase: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        //trim: true
    },
    api_token: {
        access_token: String,
        expires_in: Number,
        refresh_token: String,
        created_at: Number
    },
    vehicles: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Vehicle"
        }
    ],
    subscription: {
       agreementId: String,
       state: String,
       plan: String,
       billingAmount: String,
       billingCurrency: String,
       description: String,
       startDate: Date,
       expirationDate: Date,
       payerInfo: {
           id: String,
           name: {
               first: String, 
               last: String,
           },
           address: {
               streetLine1: String,
               streetLine2: String,
               city: String,
               state: String, 
               zipCode: String,
               countryCode: String
           }
       }
    }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Lastly, here is the register.js file (the register routes):

```
var express = require("express");
var router  = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
var User = require("../models/user.js");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require("passport");
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })


router.get("/success/:userId", function(req, res) {
    var paymentToken = req.query.token;
    //excecute the billing plan the paying user agreed to
    paypal.billingAgreement.execute(paymentToken, {}, function (error, billingAgreement) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log("INFO: Billing Agreement Executed");
            //create subscription data that will be added to user information in db
            var subscriptionUpdates = {
                subscription: {
                   agreementId: billingAgreement.id,
                   state: billingAgreement.state,
                   plan: billingAgreement.plan.payment_definitions[0].frequency,
                   billingAmount: billingAgreement.plan.payment_definitions[0].amount.value,
                   billingCurrency: billingAgreement.plan.currency_code,
                   description: billingAgreement.description,
                   startDate: new Date(),
                   expirationDate: billingAgreement.agreement_details.next_billing_date,
                   payerInfo: {
                       id: billingAgreement.payer.payer_info.payer_id,
                       name: {
                           first: billingAgreement.payer.payer_info.first_name, 
                           last: billingAgreement.payer.payer_info.last_name,
                       },
                       address: {
                           streetLine1: billingAgreement.payer.payer_info.shipping_address.line1,
                           streetLine2: billingAgreement.payer.payer_info.shipping_address.line2,
                           city: billingAgreement.payer.payer_info.shipping_address.city,
                           state: billingAgreement.payer.payer_info.shipping_address.state, 
                           zipCode: billingAgreement.payer.payer_info.shipping_address.postal_code,
                           countryCode: billingAgreement.payer.payer_info.shipping_address.country_code
                       }
                   }
                }
            };
            console.log("User ID is: " + req.params.userId);
            User.findOne(req.params.userId, subscriptionUpdates, {new: true}, function(err, updatedUser){
                console.log("User ID is: " + req.params.userId);
                if(err){
                   console.log("ERROR: User subscription information not saved to user account");
                   console.log(err);
               } 
               else{
                   console.log("INFO: " + updatedUser.subscription.plan + " subscription information added to user account");
                   console.log(updatedUser);
                   res.send(""); //need to redirect somewhere
               }
            });
        }
    }); 
});

router.get("/cancel/:userId", function(req, res) {
    //get the date
    var isoDate = new Date();
    isoDate.setDate(isoDate.getDate() + 14);
    isoDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19) + '-05:00';
    //create subscription info as trial
    var subscriptionUpdates = {
        subscription: {
            startDate: new Date(),
            expirationDate: isoDate,
            plan: "trial"
        }
    };
    //find user that was registering and update subscription information
    User.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.userId, subscriptionUpdates, {new: true}, function(err, updatedUser) {
       if(err){
           console.log("ERROR: User subscription information not saved to user account");
           console.log(err);
       } 
       else{
           console.log("INFO: Trial subscription information added to user account");
           console.log(updatedUser);
           res.send(""); //need to redirect somewhere
       }
    });
});



router.post("/", urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    //create new user account
    User.register(new User({
        "name": {
            "first": req.body.register.firstName,
            "last": req.body.register.lastName,
        },
        "username": req.body.username
        }),
        req.body.password,
        function(err, newUser){
            if(err){
                console.log("ERROR: User account failed to create in database");
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("INFO: New user created:");
                console.log(newUser);
                passport.authenticate("local", function(req, res) {return res.redirect("/admin/console");});
                //get the date
                var isoDate = new Date();
                isoDate.setDate(isoDate.getDate() + 13);
                isoDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19) + '-05:00';
                //check whic subscription plan user selected
                if(req.body.register.subscriptionType === "trial"){
                    isoDate.setDate(isoDate.getDate() + 1);
                    isoDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19) + '-05:00';
                    console.log("INFO: New user selected trial subscription");
                    var subscriptionUpdates = {
                        "subscription": {
                            "startDate": new Date(),
                            "expirationDate": isoDate,
                            "plan": "trial"
                        }
                    };
                    //update subscription information for user that registered
                    User.findOneAndUpdate(newUser._id, subscriptionUpdates, function(err, updatedUser) {
                       if(err){
                           console.log("ERROR: User subscription information not saved to user account");
                           console.log(err);
                       } 
                       else{
                           console.log("INFO: Trial subscription information added to user account");
                           console.log(updatedUser);
                           res.redirect("/admin/login"); //need to redirect somewhere
                       }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    //setup the blling plan depending on the option selected
                    if(req.body.register.subscriptionType === "monthly"){
                        var billingPlanAttributes = {
                            "name": "Monthly Billing Plan",
                            "description": "Monthly Billing Plan",
                            "type": "INFINITE",
                            "merchant_preferences": {
                                "auto_bill_amount": "yes",
                                "cancel_url": "http://" + req.get("host") + "/register/cancel/" + newUser._id,
                                "initial_fail_amount_action": "cancel",
                                "max_fail_attempts": "1",
                                "return_url": "http://" + req.get("host") + "/register/success/" + newUser._id
                            },
                            "payment_definitions": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Monthly Recurring Charge",
                                    "frequency_interval": "1",
                                    "type": "REGULAR",
                                    "cycles": "0",
                                    "frequency": "MONTH",
                                    "amount": {
                                        "currency": "USD",
                                        "value": "5"
                                    },
                                },
                            ]
                        };
                    }
                    else if(req.body.register.subscriptionType === "yearly"){
                        var billingPlanAttributes = {
                            "name": "Yearly Billing Plan",
                            "description": "Yearly Billing Plan",
                            "type": "INFINITE",
                            "merchant_preferences": {
                                "auto_bill_amount": "yes",
                                "cancel_url": "http://" + req.get("host") + "/register/cancel/" + newUser._id,
                                "initial_fail_amount_action": "cancel",
                                "max_fail_attempts": "1",
                                "return_url": "http://" + req.get("host") + "/register/success/" + newUser._id
                            },
                            "payment_definitions": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Annual Recurring Charge",
                                    "frequency_interval": "1",
                                    "type": "REGULAR",
                                    "cycles": "0",
                                    "frequency": "YEAR",
                                    "amount": {
                                        "currency": "USD",
                                        "value": "50"
                                    },
                                },
                            ]
                        };    
                    }
                    //attributes needed to update the billing plan status to active
                    var billingPlanUpdateAttributes = [
                        {
                            "op": "replace",
                            "path": "/",
                            "value": {
                                "state": "ACTIVE"
                            }
                        }
                    ];
                    //billing agreement attributes to setup individual agreements that will be sent to each paying user
                    var billingAgreementAttributes = {
                        "name": "CHANGE THIS WITH THE USER'S DB ID",
                        "description": "CHANGE WITH DB NAME + FREQUENCY + Billing Agreement",
                        "start_date": isoDate,
                        "plan": {
                            "id": "THIS VALUE WILL BE CHANGED"
                        },
                        "payer": {
                            "payment_method": "paypal"
                        },
                    };

                    // Create the billing plan
                    paypal.billingPlan.create(billingPlanAttributes, function (error, billingPlan) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                            throw error;
                        } else {
                            // Activate the plan by changing status to Active
                            paypal.billingPlan.update(billingPlan.id, billingPlanUpdateAttributes, function (error, response) {
                                if (error) {
                                    console.log(error);
                                    throw error;
                                } else {
                                    billingAgreementAttributes.plan.id = billingPlan.id;
                                    // Use activated billing plan to create agreement
                                    paypal.billingAgreement.create(billingAgreementAttributes, function (error, billingAgreement) {
                                        if (error) {
                                            console.log(error);
                                            throw error;
                                        } else {
                                            for (var index = 0; index < billingAgreement.links.length; index++) {
                                                if (billingAgreement.links[index].rel === 'approval_url') {
                                                    var approval_url = billingAgreement.links[index].href;
                                                    res.redirect(approval_url);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    );
});

module.exports = router;
```

The following line in the register.js file does not do anything (probably because the authentication is failing)

```
passport.authenticate("local", function(req, res) {return res.redirect("/admin/console");});
```

I expect it to redirect but it does not.

Also, my login route authentication fails as well. It always redirectes to the failure URL. here is the login post route:

```
router.post("/", passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: "/admin/login",
    successRedirect: "/admin/console"}),
    function(req, res) {
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. If you can also explain why what I am doing does not work it will go a long way for me to better understand authentication and how not to have this problem again. My apologies if this has been answered before but I could not find a topic similar to mine.

Comment: So I was able to figure out the problem with the login route while reading more stackoverflow topics. The issue was in the order of some code in my app.js file. I needed to move the following below the lines configuring passport.

    //setting up the routes
   app.use("/login", loginRoutes);
   app.use("/register", registerRoutes);
   //app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);

Still having issues with authenticating the user when registered.

Comment: Here is the link that helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619334/trouble-authenticating-with-passport-after-refactoring-code

Comment: I was also now able to kinda figure out why the register route was not working. I commented out the rest of the code after passport.authenticate() and it works. Still not sure why that worked so if anyone can explain  would really appreciate it.